# How to find first 32 digits of $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\gamma^n)$?

Tags: infinite-product, q-series

I need to find first 32 digits of $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\gamma^n)$ but wolframalpha's brain is too narrow to contain the result, and I don't know any software and programming to find the result. $\gamma$ is [the Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Or does it converge to a known number? Please help! Thanks

Added for Bounty. Does the mentioned infinite product have any closed form in terms of known mathematical constants?

Comment: Using Euler's pentagonal number formula gives a very rapidly convergent series. Of course, you need the value of $\gamma$ quite accurately.

Comment: [Pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem).

Answer (score 6):

Using Pochhammer symbols $$\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\gamma^n)=(\gamma ;\gamma )_{\infty }$$ A very fast way to compute it (have a look [here](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/qfunctions.html)) is
$$(\gamma ;\gamma )_{\infty }=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k \,\gamma ^{\frac{3k^2-k}{2} }$$
Consider partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{k=-p}^p (-1)^k \,\gamma ^{\frac{3k^2-k}{2} }$$ and compute for $50$ decimal places
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 0.17340542156115797462125386932229340638693672477775 \\
 6 & 0.17340542156185623295922558757637084613978106011987 \\
 7 & 0.17340542156185621287562583984349502239524993758969 \\
 8 & 0.17340542156185621287573763551045706783782602427578 \\
 9 & 0.17340542156185621287573763539033111094663184209447 \\
 10 & 0.17340542156185621287573763539033113582404282775260 \\
 11 & 0.17340542156185621287573763539033113582404183569900 \\
 12 & 0.17340542156185621287573763539033113582404183569901 \\
 13 & 0.17340542156185621287573763539033113582404183569901 \\
 14 & 0.17340542156185621287573763539033113582404183569900 \\
 15 & 0.17340542156185621287573763539033113582404183569900
\end{array}
\right)$$ For $32$ decimal places $S_9$ would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I asked [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%20(1-gamma%5En)%20from%201%20to%20infinity) and got
$0.1734054215618562128757376353903311358240418\\
356990083565526180089819971434621977210396477\\
9552159698610211689009709...$

with one click on More Digits.  I have found that sometimes when a calculation fails, close the tab, open a new one, and try again sometimes works.

Comment: So I wasn't asking it probably! Would you let me know if there is a 'closed form' for it, I mean the product as a function of other known numbers?

Comment: I would guess not, but don't really know.